# How can I convert only the relevant parts of a Json string to a Set?

Tags: java, jackson

I have some json like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "request": {
            "main_name_only": false,
            "format": "json",
            "name": "all",
            "start_date": "2019-04-01",
            "end_date": "2019-04-30",
            "limit": null,
            "country": "world",
            "show_verified": true
        },
        "status": "Success",
        "last_updated": "2019-04-30"
    },
    "top_names": [
        {
            "rank": 1,
            "name": "Jack"
        },
        {
            "rank": 2,
            "name": "John"
        },
        {
            "rank": 3,
            "name": "Mary"
        }
   ]
}
```

and I need to convert only a part of this json to `Set<String>` or `List<String>` the names. I dont need the rank and meta information. I only need to convert the `name` from `top_names`.
How can I do this using `Java` and `Jackson`?

Comment: starting with their tutorials would be a good start...

Comment: @Eugene thanks for the help. It was very useful to me!

Comment: By writing code that does that. I don't see any code. This is some very basic jackson stuff...

Comment: unfortunately this website is not about providing you any end-to-end solutions; if you show some code that you did and problems you encountered, there are plenty of people to help, otherwise you are out of luck pretty much around here

Comment: @f1sh if it is too easy for you to show me how I can do this.

Comment: Make a pojo of person with only the field name, adjust the ObjectMapper to not fail on unrecognised fields, deserialize the json to a list of person -> profit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem next way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<String> names = mapper.readTree(json).findValuesAsText("name");
```

Thanks to all for trying to help me!